# Backbone Project Approach

Tags: iphone, backbone.js, jsonp

I would like to make an application with backbone.js I understand the basics of backbone however I dont really know what the right approach to my problem might be.

I have a big jsonp file that is being retrieve from the server. So the next step would be to put the data from the jsonp file into a model. The data is bloglike containing a imgurl/title/text.

Now I could start a new model like this:

```
new modelVar = new BackboneModel;
```

However would that means that I need to create a new variable for every post I want to retrieve or could I let backbone create a set of models containg the post data.

Any suggestions book / blogs are welcome

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick answer could be "no". You can let Backbone loading data in models using a Backbone Collection.

E.g.

```
new App.Photos([
  {url:"http://(...)_1.png", title:"photo1"},
  {url:"http://(...)_2.png", title:"photo2"}, 
  {url:"http://(...)_3.png", title:"photo3"}
 ]);
```

[image]

You just have to get an array of objects in argument when you create your collection prototype. Backbone will automatically create models based on the model attribute defined into the collection object. It's particularly fitted to your needs because you just have to put in argument the parsed json response and your models will be created.

I suggest you Backbone Marionette which is a good choice to start with Backbone implementation in order to get best practices.

https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette